# How to Sort/Order/Prioritise HttpMessageConverters in SpringBoot 1.5.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, content-negotiation, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need to support XML and JSON in one of my spring-boot 1.5.12 service and  the following dependencies on classpath

- jackson-dataformat-xml
- jackson-json dependencies(shipped as part of spring-web starter)

I've created **MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter** Bean to support XML with Jackson itself (for uniformity with JSON)

```java
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlHttpConverter(ObjectMapper xmlMapper) {
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        xmlConverter.setObjectMapper(xmlMapper);
        return xmlConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper xmlMapper() {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
        xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        return xmlMapper;
    }
```

but since I made these changes, XML is taking priority over JSON in all aspects(RestTemplate calls and service **/health** and **/info** checks)

I've added Content-Type header in RestTemplate calls, but our CI-CD Infra invokes actuator endpoints, now that's affected, I wanted to sort/order the converters with too little changes or make JSON as default Content-Type for the service.

I know that /health.json and /info.json works but I can't ask Infra team to change the their logic for this service,

I saw the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters) I liked the approach, but I want to know how to get all the existing converters through injection but not by inheriting WebMvcConfigureAdapter..

Please suggest me any other better way of solving the problem.

Comment: You don't need to create the `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter ` Spring Boot does that already when it detects the Jackson XML classes on the classpath. What is returned depends on the headers being send to the server, it detects which return type to prefer over the other.

Comment: Thanks, will remove it then, but without any Accept header, I want the service to default to application/json instead of xml, how to do that ?

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried removing but the ObjectMapper config is ignored if I don't declare MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter

Comment: Configure that in the `application.properties` by adding the features you want. To configure what to do when no accept header (or suitable mapping is found) add a `WebMvcConfigurer` and implement the `configureContentNegotiation` to modify the behavior.